# fatfree SQL error handling

Tags: php, exception, fat-free-framework

If, for whatever reason, there is an error in creation of an entry using the mapper I get an error.

I'd like to do a custom notification and fail gracefully like so...

```
try {
    $request->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->utils->errorNotify($f3,'could not create a request entry',http_build_query($_POST));
    return null;
}
```

is this possible with F3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

\DB\SQL is a subclass of PDO so it can throw catchable PDO exceptions. Since these are disabled by default, you need to enable them first. This can be done in 2 different ways:

- at instantiation time, for all transactions:

  `$db = new \DB\SQL($dsn, $user, $pwd, array( \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ));`
- later on in the code, on a per-transaction basis:

  `$db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Once PDO exceptions are enabled, just catch them as other exceptions:

```
try {
  $db->exec('INSERT INTO mytable(id) VALUES(?)','duplicate_id');
} catch(\PDOException $e) {
  $err=$e->errorInfo;
  //$err[0] contains the error code (23000)
  //$err[2] contains the driver specific error message (PRIMARY KEY must be unique)
}
```

This also works with DB mappers, since they rely on the same DB\SQL class:

```
$db=new \DB\SQL($dsn,$user,$pwd,array(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>\PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$mytable=new \DB\SQL\Mapper($db,'mytable');
try {
  $mytable->id='duplicate_id';
  $mytable->save();//this will throw an exception
} catch(\PDOException $e) {
  $err=$e->errorInfo;
  echo $err[2];//PRIMARY KEY must be unique
}
```