# Handle 'Duplicate-entry error' in fat-free framework

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fat-free-framework

How to handle error when duplicate entries are inserted into table?
I tried the following and it is not working.

```
function leaveBalanceRecord($f3)
{
    $sql = 
    "
    INSERT 
    INTO users_leave_balance (user_id, period, leave_type, leave_balance, rollable_till_date)
    VALUES (134, '2017-01', 1, 10.00, NULL)";
    $results = $this->db->exec($sql);
    if(!$results)
    {
        return 'Duplicate Entries';
    }
    return $results;
}
```

How to handle the error and update the record instead in case this error arises? 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What's the duplicated field? I believe you should first select a row with that field's value and if it exists, update it, otherwise use the insert query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two solutions for your case:

1) Take benefit of the MySQL `REPLACE INTO` syntax:

```
$sql='REPLACE INTO users_leave_balance etc.';
$this->db->exec($sql);
```

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html):

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

2) Catch the PDO exception:

```
$sql='INSERT INTO users_leave_balance etc.';
try {
  $this->db->exec($sql);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
  $err=$e->errorInfo;
  if ($err[0]==23000) {
    // duplicate key: do something
  } else {
    // any other error
  }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518106/fatfree-sql-error-handling/30523332#30523332) for details on how to enable PDO exceptions.

Comment: thank you for the solutions.. very much appreciated.. :)
one extra thing.. error code = 23000 is for "duplicate entries"?

Comment: It is "Integrity constraint violation". See [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jenut/ch08_06.htm) or [there](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58231/appd.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like you should just add another execute sql, with update, instead of comment in your return section